# no matching constructor for initialization of 'listNode struct

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, initializer-list

The following method insert makes use of the constructor for the struct listNode.

```
void list::insert(size_t i){
    if (head == nullptr){
        head = new listNode(nullptr,i);
        tail = head;
        ++len;
    }
    listNode* new_node = new listNode(nullptr,i);
    tail->next = new_node;
    tail = new_node;
}
```

definition of listNode

```
struct listNode{
        ////@: index into the input buffer
        listNode* next;
        size_t index;
};
```

in addition to the error given in the title of this post, I also get the note

```
 note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not
      viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
struct listNode{
```

this doesn't make sense to me. As clearly i provided two arguments in my initialization and it should use lexicogrphical binding of paramaters to actual paramaters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
head = new listNode(nullptr,i);
```

is wrong since `listNode` does not have any user defined constructors. Hence, you cannot use the syntax `listNode(nullptr, i)` to construct one.

Use

```
head = new listNode{nullptr, i}; // This is member-member wise initialization
```

Similarly, instead of

```
listNode* new_node = new listNode(nullptr, i);
```

use

```
listNode* new_node = new listNode{nullptr, i};
```

Comment: "It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish there." sorry had a typo in the code its been fixed

Comment: @DrawkcabEsrever, understood.